# jQuery animate on scroll to a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to reduce an elements top padding smoothly on scroll. At the same time i want the 2 child elements to fade, 1 of them out and 1 in. Ive got the fading right but i cant get the padding top to work correctly. Can anybody see what may be wrong with my function?

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    $('.transitionParent').css({
        'padding-top' : $(this).scrollTop()-($(this).scrollTop()/500)
    });
    $('.ipadOutline').css({
        'opacity' : 1-($(this).scrollTop()/500)
    });
    $('.ipadPhoto').css({
        'opacity' : 0+($(this).scrollTop()/500)
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pXdhB/1/

---

I've also tried (with no luck!)

```
var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.transitionParent').css('padding-top', '-' + (100 - fromTop));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/pXdhB/7/

#### JQUERY

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.transitionParent').stop().animate({
        'padding-top': $(this).scrollTop() - ($(this).scrollTop() / 500)
    }, 1000, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('.ipadOutline').css({
        'opacity': 1 - ($(this).scrollTop() / 500)
    });
    $('.ipadPhoto').css({
        'opacity': 0 + ($(this).scrollTop() / 500)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
   $(window).scroll(function () { 
            $('.transitionParent').css({
                'padding-top' : 100 - ($(this).scrollTop()-($(this).scrollTop())/500)
            });
            $('.ipadOutline').css({
                'opacity' : 1-($(this).scrollTop()/500)
            });
            $('.ipadPhoto').css({
                'opacity' : 0+($(this).scrollTop()/500)
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DkM8a/

Comment: Sort of @Spassvogel, I want the padding top to gradually decrease relevant to the window scroll if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here is relevant code:

```
var st = $(this).scrollTop(),
    newPt = 100 - st;

console.log(st + " " + newPt)
if (newPt > 0) {
    $('.transitionParent').css({
        'padding-top' : newPt
    })
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pXdhB/8/